# MySQL Insert Update Satement from select

Tags: mysql

How to insert and update in one query from temp table. I have finaltable in which primary keys are Callid and segment

```
INSERT INTO `finaltable` (select * from tempdb.Matched);
```

Comment: are you trying to insert a new `row` and update an old row at the same time?

Comment: You cannot insert and update in a single query. There is as insert ... select ... syntax and an insert ... on duplicate key update ... Both have been repeatedly discussed here on SO. Pls provide more details as to what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: yes  i am trying to insert a new row and update an old row at the same time